# Copy & paste non-ASCII characters to an Emacs window from another window doesn't work correctly

Tags: clipboard, emacs, unicode, special-characters

I work with emacs with iso-8859-1 coding system. I use emacs23. I have these lines in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'iso-8859-1)
(set-selection-coding-system 'iso-8859-1)
```

However, if I try to copy a non-ASCII character from another window and paste it to my emacs window, it doesn't work correctly. For instance, if I try to copy and paste "ì" I get "Ã¬". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the best thing to do is switch emacs to UTF-8.